# Why isn't my while loop condition working?

Tags: java

When I try to use a while loop it won't follow the conditions I set in the while. Like if I put `while s1 != "n")` it will continue even if s1 = n. It does the opposite when I try to use `while s1 == "y")` and it very irritating. I'm trying to make a factorial calculator that prompts the user if they would like to keep going or stop.

Here's the full code:

```
package factorial;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int factorial = 1;
    int number = 6;
    int i = 1;
    String s1 = "y";

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

while(s1 != "n") {
    System.out.println("Enter an N:");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();
    while(i <= number) {
        factorial *= i;
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Factorial = "+factorial);
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (y/n)");
    s1 = keyboard.next();
}
keyboard.close();
System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
}
}
```

Comment: it is `while(!s1.equals("n"))` for strings.

Answer (score -1):

As @Debabrata says use equals for strings, replace:

```
while(s1 != "n") {
```

with

```
while(!s1.equals("n")) {
```